# React.js Understanding setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been having a go at learning React.js by writing a small calculator application. I thought things were going quite well until I learned that setState is asynchronous and my mutations therefore do not get immediately applied.

So my question is, what is the best way to keep a running total based upon the values being added to an input. Take the following example:

```
var Calculator = React.createClass({
  total : 0,

  getInitialState : function(){
    return { 
      value : '0'
    };
  },

  onValueClicked : function (value) {
    var actual, total, current = this.state.value;

    if(value === '+') {
      actual = this.total = parseInt(this.total, 10) + parseInt(current, 10);
    } else {
      if(parseInt(current, 10) === 0) {
        actual = value;
      } else {
        actual = current.toString() + value;
      }
    }

    this.setState({ value : actual });
  },

  render : function () {
    return (
      <div className="calc-main">
        <CalcDisplay value={this.state.value} />
        <CalcButtonGroup range="0-10" onClick={this.onValueClicked} />
        <CalcOpButton type="+" onClick={this.onValueClicked} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var CalcDisplay = React.createClass({
  render : function () {
    return (
      <input type="text" name="display" value={this.props.value} />
    );
  }
});

var CalcButtonGroup = React.createClass({
  render : function () {
    var i, buttons = [], range = this.props.range.split('-');

    for(i = range[0]; i < range[1]; i++) {
      var handler = this.props.onClick.bind(null, i);

      buttons.push(<CalcNumberButton key={i} onClick={ handler } />);
    }

    return (
      <div className="calc-btn-group">{ buttons }</div>
    );
  }
});

var CalcNumberButton = React.createClass({
  render : function () {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.key}</button>
    );
  }
});

var CalcOpButton = React.createClass({
  render : function () {
    var handler, op = this.props.type;

    handler = this.props.onClick.bind(null, op);

    return (
      <button onClick={handler}>{op}</button>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<Calculator />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

In the example above I gave up completely on storing the total within the state and kept it outside. I've read that you can have a callback run when setState has finished but in the case of a calculator I need it to be snappy and update quickly. If the state isn't getting updated with each button press and I quickly hit the buttons - things are going to fall out of sync. Is the callback all I am missing or am I thinking about this in completely the wrong way?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: To be honest if you don't need to use `this.total` in the `render` function at all, then it's quite fine to keep it outside of state.  Stuff needs to be in state only if any change to it should `always` cause a re-render.  If you don't actually need to always re-render when changing this.total then you can leave things as they are.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in the current implementation, if you call `setState` in response to an event, the state will settle before any further events are dispatched.

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that I was console.log'ing the state values. However I found that if I tried to store more than one item in the state and changed one field in one place and another elsewhere - the two values would fall out of sync. i.e. if I stored the operand in the state and checked for its existence in the next interaction - it wouldn't always be set.

Answer (score 2):

It's asynchronous, but much faster than the fastest possible human click.

---

Aside from that, you should declare instance variables in componentDidMount, e.g.

```js
componentDidMount: function(){
  this.total = 0;
}
```

... but in this case you probably want to store it in state.

---

.split returns an array of strings, you want to be using numbers:

```js
range = this.props.range.split('-').map(Number)
```

Or avoid the strings altogether (prefered) with one of these:

```js
<CalcButtonGroup range={[0, 10]} onClick={this.onValueClicked} />
<CalcButtonGroup range={{from: 0, till: 10}} onClick={this.onValueClicked} />
```

Comment: I don't agree with *but in this case you probably want to store it in state*. The `state` is only for UI state **only**, use another (subscribe) variable for logic state.

Comment: You need to have the data used to produce the output of render in state+props. So you could store the total, or the sequence of actions, or however you want to represent it. But if it affects render and it's not in props or state, you run into issues quickly and things fall out of sync.

Comment: See my post. Besides, another idea to resolve *if it affects render and it's not in props or state* is to subscribe `this.state` on that variable. And, only that variable can update `this.state`. Flow like this: `data` -> calculations -> `data` -> `this.state`.

Comment: I think we're agreeing. In case you didn't notice (I often don't), this question is from 10 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have define the `total` variable for your business logic state. Why not store more information like that?

```
var Calculator = React.createClass({
  previous: 0, // <-- previous result
  current: 0, // <-- current display
  op: '', // <-- pending operator

  getInitialState : function(){
    return { 
      value : '0'
    };
  },

  onValueClicked : function (value) {
    var actual;

    if(value === '+') {
      this.previous = this.current;
      this.op = '+';
      actual = 0; // start a new number
    } else if (value === '=') {
      if (this.op === '+') {
        actual = this.previous + this.current;
      } else {
        actual = this.current; // no-op
      }
    } else {
      actual = current * 10 + value;
    }

    this.current = actual; // <-- business logic state update is synchronous
    this.setState({ value : String(actual) }); // <-- this.state is only for UI state, asynchronous just fine
  },

  render : function () {
    return (
      <div className="calc-main">
        <CalcDisplay value={this.state.value} />
        <CalcButtonGroup range="0-10" onClick={this.onValueClicked} />
        <CalcOpButton type="+" onClick={this.onValueClicked} />
        <CalcOpButton type="=" onClick={this.onValueClicked} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

The basic idea to resolve `this.state` is use other variables to store your business logic state, and reserve `this.state` only for UI state.

*PS.* A real calculator has more complex business logic than this. You should define every state and state machine clearly in spec.

Comment: If you want to separate business logic from presentation state, move the business logic to a container component, not to instance properties on the component.